# Databricks Spark SQL subquery based query throws TreeNodeException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am running a pretty simple query in databricks notebook which involves a subquery.

```
select recorddate, count(*) 
from( select record_date as recorddate, column1 
      from table1 
      where record_date >= date_sub(current_date(), 1) 
    )t
group by recorddate
order by recorddate
```

I get the following exception:
Error in SQL statement: package.TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: recorddate

And when  remove the order by clause, the query runs fine. I see some posts talking about similar issues but exactly the same. Is this a known behavior? Any workaround/fix for this?

Comment: in the sub query i see  aliasing the column ,  record_date as date

Comment: That was a typo introduced replacing the actual table and column names with stubs. Fixed it now.

Comment: can you try without aliasing the column.

Answer (score 0):

Working well for me, (spark = 2.4.5) I think problem is something different-

```scala
 val df = spark.sql("select current_date() as record_date, '1' column1")
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * +-----------+-------+
      * |record_date|column1|
      * +-----------+-------+
      * |2020-07-29 |1      |
      * +-----------+-------+
      */
    
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
    spark.sql(
      """
        |select recorddate, count(*)
        |from( select record_date as recorddate, column1
        |      from table1
        |      where record_date >= date_sub(current_date(), 1)
        |    )t
        |group by recorddate
        |order by recorddate
        |
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+--------+
      * |recorddate|count(1)|
      * +----------+--------+
      * |2020-07-29|1       |
      * +----------+--------+
      */
```

Comment: I am doing this in databricks notebook with a direct SQL query. Hmm. This could be a databricks specific issue then. Not sure.